# Jquery extract text using .text() except particular tag

Tags: jquery, html

I've an HTML

```
<td class="abc"><b><span>NO</span>YES</b> ALL</td>
```

I am trying to get text of class abc without span tag. 
For eg. in above HTML I want only "YES ALL".

```
$('td.abc').text() returns NOYES ALL

$('td.abc').clone.find('span').remove().text() returns NO
```

Can anyone help me getting all text in above HTML except particular tag, here except tag span so that I could return "YES ALL". I want a one line solution.

Comment: I doubt that the second line returns "ALL". Assuming that `.clone.find` is just a typo (it should be `.clone().find`, it probably returns "NO", the text of the `span` element.

Comment: @FelixKling, thanks for pointing. I've corrected my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.clone()` is a method not a property, also since you are using `.find()` after removing the element, you should use `.end()` method for getting the previous collection, i.e the `td` element.

```
var text = $('td.abc').clone().find('span').remove().end().text();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/keY9Q/

Comment: Thanks, I've forgot to use .end()